# Marginal and joint probabilities in a contingency table

Tags: probability

I have a hard time understanding marginal probabilities and joint probabilities w.r.t contingency tables. I have a textbook that states that marginal probabilities are single variables that can be calculated like this: P(X=b) = 40 / 100 = 0.4. However, my lecture notes note that if X and Y are independent then marginal probabilities are the same as joint probabilities and can thus be calculated as P(X=b)P(Y=2) = (20/100)(40/100) = 0.08. But if I do it by checking the counts at the actual values i.e. X=b, Y=2. Then we get 10/40 for the probability that X=b and 10/20 for the probability that Y=2. This gives (1/2)(1/4) = (1/8) = 0.125. Then there is also the joint probability of P(X=b, Y=2) = 10/100 = 0.1 .

So I end up with 4 probabilities:

- P(X=b) = 0.4
- P(X=b)P(Y=2) = 0.08
- P(X=b)P(Y=2) = 0.125
- P(X=b, Y=2) = 0.1

What is the difference between the 0.08 and 0.125 and what am I overlooking here.

| x/y | **1** | **2** | **3** | **sum**(x) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a** | 2 | 5 | 3 | 10 |
| **b** | 10 | 20 | 10 | 40 |
| **c** | 8 | 35 | 7 | 40 |
| **sum**(y) | 20 | 60 | 20 | 100 |

Comment: How exactly did you get the values $\frac{10}{40}$ and $\frac{10}{20}$ for $\Pr(X=b)$ and $\Pr(Y=2)$?

Comment: @periwinkle the cell where x=b and y=1 come together has 10 records. I divide this by the total of Pr(Y=1) and Pr(X=b)

Comment: You seem to be confusing $Y=1$ and $Y=2$.  In fact $P(Y=1)=\frac{20}{100}$ and $P(Y=2)=\frac{60}{100}$ as marginal figures

Comment: x in {a,b,c} and y in {1,2,3}. The cell where x=b,y=1 has 10 records. You can do 10/20, where 20 is the sum of records where y=1 and 10/40 where 40 is the sum where x=b